# how to get data from ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i am calling ajax and my success function says

```
success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.data);
},
```

And my response is

```
{"data":{"response":"{\"ResCode\":\"TPB009\",\"ResStatus\":1}","http_code":200}}
```

i want to fetch ResCode so i tried this

```
console.log(data.data.response['ResStatus']);
        console.log(data.data.response['ResCode']);
```

**but it is undefine any help?**

Comment: Please provide the complete code for how you are making the AJAX request and handling the response

Comment: Did you specify `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: yes my controller pass response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.data.response` is a JSON string, you need to parse it.

```
let response = JSON.parse(data.data.response);
console.log(response.ResStatus, response.ResCode);
```

Comment: undefine says that

Comment: Are you sure the original output is from `console.log(data.data)`, not `console.log(data)`?

Comment: i have response in console.log(data.data.response) {"ResCode":"TPB009","ResMsg":"Client information does not exist","ResStatus":1,"sign":"d6+G9zk399d0NkPjkRCxblv9UY5XwZrgl1SW6xPIngelA+Rik4p/EdxTxO1fj7P+lVsQj4gbafTguphcQZ5VHA=="}

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof data.data.response)` show?

Comment: it says typeof string

Comment: And what does `console.log(response)` show after the assignment?

Comment: I had typos in my answer, try it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237330/discussion-between-hamza-qureshi-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

Your response seems to be in JSON format, use JSON parse

```
success: function (data) {
   var jso = JSON.parse(data);
    ...
},
```